# Won't print out names help please

Tags: javascript, function, callback

```
let people = ['John','Sally','Jake','Chris'];

const logPerson = (person, index) => {
  console.log('${index} - Hello ${person}');
};

people.forEach(logPerson);
```

it keeps printing out like this

"${index} - Hello ${person}"

how do I get it to display the names & index value code looks right as far as I can tell and from what I searched on google.

Comment: You need to use backticks, not single quotes for template literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let people = ['John','Sally','Jake','Chris'];

const logPerson = (person, index) => {
  console.log(`${index} - Hello ${person}`);
};

people.forEach(logPerson);
```

You need to use the BACKTICK, not the regular quote.

```
 console.log(`${index} - Hello ${person}`);
```

If you are on the US keyboard, that symbol is just above the `tab` key, right beside the `1` key.

Answer (score 0):

```
const logPerson = (person, index) => {
  console.log(`${index} - Hello ${person}`);
};

people.forEach(logPerson);
```

In order to reference variables like this you need to use a backquote. However, if you are going to use regular quotes, you can use commas within your string if that is easier:

```
const logPerson = (person, index) => {
  console.log(index, "- Hello", person);
};
```

The code above will give you the same output. You can also use the plus operator. Whichever form you choose is up to you, but use the backquote when you are trying to reference variables the way you need. Use normal quotes when attempting to reference variables normally and concatenating them within a string using the + or , operators.